# What is the difference between endomysium and sarcolemma

Tags: muscles

They both are lining of muscles so how can we differentiate these two? Please answer in simple terms.

Comment: What's an endomyceus? When I search google it says 'endomysium'. Am I still new in the field or is the spelling wrong?

Comment: Sorry,it is endomysium

Comment: If you try "endomysium" in Google, the very first result (wikipedia) is very clear: endomysium is a layer of connective tissue that surrounds the muscle cell, whose membrane is called sarcolemma.

Comment: **Homework questions** and **trivial questions about basic biological concepts** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check this other image too from google. A single muscle cell or fibre has been magnified to show the sarcolemma and other contents like eccentric/peripheral nuclei as well as sarcoplasm. It's not the best image but hope this is ok.

Comment: If you have more information to add to your answer, please use the `edit` link (between `share` and `delete` just below the text of your answer). Please do not create a new answer unless it is *substantially* different from the first. Finally, you must cite/link to the sources of all images you use in answers (and questions). It helps to provide context, may give additional sources of information, and is just scientific common sense - you **always** cite your sources.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Structure of a skeletal muscle]

Just to illustrate Gerardo's answer, this picture is provided. The endomysium as you see is a layer of connective tissue which surrounds the individual muscle fibres (cells) (in between one muscle cell and the next) but each muscle cell in particular is lined or covered by a plasma membrane called the sarcolemma.